# Scrollable dropdown menu in element ui framework

Tags: css, vuejs2

How does one implement scrollable dropdown menu using element ui framework? I have many items I need to populate the dropdown with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the select-tag, a scrollbar is added automatically when to many elements are inside.